# Tower of Hanoi - User is moving disks (c)

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to make a c program that first asks user inputs the number of disks, and then the user is allowed to move the disks freely.
However, it must have the rules of the original Tower of Hanoi, such as the bigger disks cannot be placed over smaller ones.
Also, the poles are '0, 1, 2'

For example,

**input :** 5
**output :**
0: 5 4 3 2 1
1: x
2: x

**input :** 0 1
**output :**

0: 5 4 3 2
1: 1
2: x

**input :** 3 3
program ends because there is no pole 3

I would like to get a hint? sort of like a way I can start coding.
Thanks!

Comment: Have a think about how you can break down this problem into smaller pieces. Consider what problems you have done in the past which are like these pieces, and use these to try to help you solve those smaller piece problems. If you get stuck, show us what you have done and explain why it doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: oh. Thanks! I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make 2d array representing 3 poles.

Get input from user and initialize

```
arr[2][number] = {0};
for(i=0; i<number; i++){
    arr[0][i] = number-i;
}
```

And start a loop which helps user to input 2 numbers and operate moving.
You need to check several conditions like

1. if k > l, arr[x][k] < arr[x][l] where x, k, l is proper number
2. if input is not proper number (like ur example)

Maybe code can be like below.

```
scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
while(n1<3 && n1>=0 && n2 <= number &&n2 > 0){
    /// deleteDisk: find last component which is not zero and make it zero and return deleted disk size
    disk = deleteDisk(arr, n1);    
    /// addDisk: change first zero to disk, return 0 if violates condition 1
    err = addDisk(arr, n2, disk);
    if (err == 0)
        break;
    /// arrayPrint: print 2d array til zero
    arrayPrint;
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
}
```